# argument of type uint8_t is incompatible with parameter of type char*

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, uint8t

I've been getting the title error recently and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, anyone have any ideas? relevant code below

Rom.h

```
//Rom.h
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
struct ROM {
  uint8_t* memblock;
  std::fstream rom;
  std::streampos size;
  int flag;

  void ROM::LoadROM(std::string path, int flag);
  void ROM::BinaryDump(std::string path, std::streampos size);
}
```

Rom.cpp

```
//Rom.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Rom.h"

void ROM::LoadROM(std::string path, int flag) {
  this->rom.open(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

  if (rom.is_open()) {
    this->size = rom.tellg();
    std::cout << "\nThe Rom is " << rom.tellg() << " byte(s) long." << std::endl;
    this->memblock = new uint8_t[(unsigned int)this->size];
    std::cout << rom.tellg() << " Bytes of memory have been allocated" << std::endl;
    rom.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    rom.read(this->memblock, (unsigned int)this->size);
    std::cout << "The contents of the file are stored in memory" << std::endl;
    rom.close();
    if (flag == 0) {
    }
    else {
        BinaryDump(path, this->size);
    }
  }
}

void ROM::BinaryDump(std::string path, std::streampos size) {
  std::fstream binDump(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

  binDump.write(this->memblock, size);
  delete[] this->memblock;
  binDump.close();
  std::cout << "The ROM has been dumped" << std::endl;
}
```

Sorry if this is completely obvious but I feel lost here.

Comment: Compilers will generally tell you on which *line* an error occurs. Use the force, young Padawan :-)

Comment: Please show the exact error message and indicate which source line it corresponds to

Comment: Not related to the question, but your class violates the Rule of Three. To fix this, use `vector<uint8_t>` instead of `uint8_t *`.

Comment: @M.M, I'm not sure how that's a violation/fix for the RO3/5. Not saying using a vector isn't a good idea but I think that's separate from ensuring you define all the 3/5 methods for the `rom` class if you define one.

Comment: @paxdiablo I mean that memory will be leaked when the object is assigned or copied in some cases

Comment: @M.M, yeah, I got that, I just don't think it's the intent of the ROx. But I could be wrong, it wouldn't be the first time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uint8_t` and `char` are different types. (Well - this is system dependent, but on your system they are different). You cannot use the two names interchangeably.

Your question did not mention what line gave the error, but if you look that up you will find that you are passing `uint8_t *` where in fact the function expects `char *`.

I guess it would be `rom.read` . If so then you could fix the problem with:

```
rom.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>(memblock), size );
```

You do not need to use redundant `unsigned int` casts or `this->` prefixes.

Another possible solution would be to make `memblock` have type `char *`.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<char *>(memblock)` <- is that going to be safe?

Comment: @deW1 Yes it will be safe

Comment: shoot, completely forgot about giving the line number, thanks!